# SQL Reporting Builder duplicate values

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report in sql reporting builder and encountered duplication.

[image]

| computer name | processor | ram | HDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | intel core i5 | Crucial/Channel A | Toshiba 931 |
|  |  |  | PH6 223 |
|  |  | Crucial/Channel B | Toshiba 931 |
|  |  |  | PH6 223 |

Query:

```
  SELECT   DISTINCT 
     SYS.Netbios_Name0 AS 'Netbios Name'
    ,Versions.Model0 AS 'Model'
    ,Versions.UserName0 AS 'User'
    ,format(USR.LastConsoleUse0, 'dd, MMMM yyyy') AS 'lastLogonTime'
    , NewBios.BIOSVersion0 AS 'Current Bios Version'
    , NewBios.SerialNumber0 AS 'Current Bios SerialNumber'           
    , NewProcessor.Name0 AS 'Current CPU Name'
    , Cast(Cast(NewMem.TotalPhysicalMemory0 AS bigint) / 1048576 As numeric) AS 'Current Physical Memory (GB)'
    , NewPHMEM.DeviceLocator0 AS 'Current Device Locator'
    , NewPHMEM.Manufacturer0 AS 'Current Manufacturer mem'
    , NewPHMEM.PartNumber0 AS 'Current Part Number'
    , NewPHMEM.SerialNumber0 AS 'Current Serial Number mem'
    , NewDisk.Model0 AS 'Current Model Disk'
    , NewDisk.SerialNumber0 AS 'Current Serial Disk'
    , Cast(Cast(NewDisk.Size0 AS bigint) / 1073741824 AS numeric) AS 'Current Size Disk (GB)'
FROM 
        CM_IN1.dbo.v_R_System  SYS
        LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM Versions
            ON Sys.ResourceID = Versions.ResourceID 
                LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_PC_BIOS  NewBios 
                        ON SYS.ResourceID = NewBios.ResourceID
               LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_PROCESSOR NewProcessor 
                      ON SYS.ResourceID = NewProcessor.ResourceID
              LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_PHYSICAL_MEMORY NewPHMEM
                       ON Sys.ResourceID = NewPHMEM.ResourceID
              LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY NewMem
                      ON Sys.ResourceID = NewMem.ResourceID
           LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER USR
              ON USR.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
        LEFT JOIN CM_IN1.dbo.v_GS_PHYSICAL_DISK NewDisk
                      ON Sys.ResourceID = NewDisk.ResourceID
```

How to make HDD not repeat the values?

Comment: Can you post example data?

Comment: Such an example?

Comment: Sorry, an example of the data in a table/view